# What is the "generalized degree" of a map $f: \tilde B \to \mathbf G$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Let $\mathbf G$ be a compact, simple, and simply-connected Lie group. Let $G: \Sigma \to \mathbf G$ be a smooth map, where $\Sigma$ is a Riemann surface. Also, let $\tilde G$ be an extension of $G$ to a 3-manifold $B$ with boundary $\partial B=\Sigma$.

A physics paper claims that, the integral
$$\frac{ik}{24\pi} \int_{\tilde B} \langle \tilde G^{-1} d\tilde G, [\tilde G^{-1} d\tilde G, \tilde G^{-1} d\tilde G]\rangle$$
is $2\pi ik\mathbb Z$-valued, and furthermore it is related to the generalized degree of the map $\tilde G: \tilde B \to \mathbf G$. I am not sure what is $\tilde B$.

The following is the relevant part of the paper:

[image]

**Question: Why the above integral is quantized, and related to the generalized degree?**

The degree that I know is the "de Rham cohomology sense". Given a smooth map $f:M\to M$ on a compact connected orientable $m$-manifold $M$, the degree $\deg f \in \mathbb Z$ is characterized by the following condition. For all $\omega \in \Omega^m(M)$, we have
$$\int_M f^*\omega = (\deg f) \int_M \omega.$$

Comment: $S_\Sigma(G)$ depends on the choice of the chosen 3-manifold $B$. The integral (marked blue) describes the difference between two choices $B_1,B_2$ both with boundary $\Sigma$. Gluing $B_1$ and $B_2$ along the common boundary gives the closed 3 manifold $\tilde B$. The integrality should be deducable from the normalisation of the killing form, but I do not have the details.. Do you know Chern-Simons forms / theory?

Comment: @Jonas I think your definition of $\tilde B$ is correct. I have a bit of knowledge in Chern-Simons form, but the blue integral is different with that. (The Chern-Simons form is roughly the differential of $\mathrm{tr}\left(A\wedge dA + \frac23 A\wedge A \wedge A\right).$